# combine multiple text files and remove duplicates

Tags: shell, unix, text, merge, duplicates

I have around 350 text files (and each file is around 75MB). I'm trying to combine all the files and remove duplicate entries. The file is in the following format:

```
ip1,dns1
ip2,dns2
...
```

I wrote a small shell script to do this

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in data/*
do
    cat "$file" >> dnsFull
done
sort dnsFull > dnsSorted
uniq dnsSorted dnsOut
rm dnsFull dnsSorted
```

I'm doing this processing often and was wondering if there is anything I could do to improve the processing next time when I run it. I'm open to any programming language and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: you could also give sort -m a try --> it will sort the individual files and merge them accordingly hence should saving quite a bit of  time .... the -m option was available espl for scenario like this ... ie sort -m file* | uniq -u

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First off, you're not using the full power of `cat`. The loop can be replaced by just

```
cat data/* > dnsFull
```

assuming that file is initially empty.

Then there's all those temporary files that force programs to wait for hard disks (commonly the slowest parts in modern computer systems). Use a pipeline:

```
cat data/* | sort | uniq > dnsOut
```

This is still wasteful since `sort` alone can do what you're using `cat` and `uniq` for; the whole script can be replaced by

```
sort -u data/* > dnsOut
```

If this is still not fast enough, then realize that sorting takes O(n lg n) time while deduplication can be done in linear time with Awk:

```
awk '{if (!a[$0]++) print}' data/* > dnsOut
```

Comment: Note that the final awk can be simplified to `awk '!a[$0]++' data/*`

Comment: I deleted my perl answer because 350 * 75MB = more than 26GB - in-memory sorting (like awk) can cause too much memory swapping.

Comment: Sorry, what does awk '!a[$0]++' do? Does it compare the first element, or the full line?

Comment: In my case, using awk to dedupe in "linear time" kept running out of memory. Somehow sort -u is what got the job done.